# Import JSON data to Java without escape characters

Tags: java, json, string

I'm currently importing Json from a .json webpage using an HttpResponse. I then use `String Json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())` to get the Json data as a String.

However, this messes up the format of my String, and it ends up looking like this:

```
\"{\\n    fault: '',\\n    width: 2800,\\n    height: 1400\\n.
```

Due to the extra escape characters that were added, I'm unable to parse it how I would like.

Is there a way to import the Json without Java messing up the format and automatically extra escape characters?

Comment: You can try something like this: `String responseString = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);`

Comment: what does response.getEntity() look like? is it possible to cut it out if it is the one causing your string to go haywire?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library. It is library for java which works with Json.